# MAMP setting up a host

Tags: web-server, httpd.conf, web, serveralias

I've a website which use a google api by a specific domain. Then my google App work on domain like dev.mydomain.com

So i need to create a VH but it doesn't works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject
  ServerName www.dev.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias dev.dev.mydomain.com
  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

why when i call http://dev.mydomain.com it return me an error "can't find the server www.dev.mydomain.com :/ (i work on httpd-vhost.conf and i've enabled it in my http.conf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a entry in the host.conf file

```
127.0.0.1 dev.mydomain.com
```

Comment: It works ! The tutorials might add this at the ends :/